# Exception attempting to construct a HERE maps HitArea object

Tags: javascript, here-api

The `H.map.Icon` class includes a `hitArea` option that I'm assuming is appropriate for adjusting the selection area tolerance for an icon or marker. Unfortunately the documentation is a bit sparse and the following is throwing an exception:

```
var marker = new H.map.Marker(location, { icon: new H.map.Icon("/Content/images/anchordot.png", { 
      size: { w: 20, h: 20 }, 
      anchor: { x: 10, y: 10 }, 
      hitArea: new H.map.HitArea(H.map.HitArea.ShapeType.CIRCLE, [20]) }) });
```

I have no idea really what the optional second argument needs to be for the `HitArea` constructor, but I get an exception with or without that argument.  The details of the exception are not at all helpful.

Ideas?

Comment: Please share the error message as part of your question.

Comment: The exception message is: message : "H.map.HitArea (Argument #1)"  - not that helpful

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the wrong number of parameters to the array. For circle, we require three parameters- namely the coordinates and the radius. So your example should look like the below. Happy Coding!

```
var marker = new H.map.Marker(location, { icon: new H.map.Icon("/Content/images/anchordot.png", { 
      size: { w: 20, h: 20 }, 
      anchor: { x: 10, y: 10 }, 
      hitArea: new H.map.HitArea(H.map.HitArea.ShapeType.CIRCLE, [0,0,20]) }) });
```